# Why is .index() resolving as a number in this statement while .parent().index() is resolving as a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the code, it is referencing a TD and "farmland" is the id of the table:

```
$("#farmland td").click(function(){
        $("#console").html($(this).index() + 1 + ", " + $(this).parent().index() + 1);
    });
```

When I click a TD, I am getting 1,01 or 1,11 or 1,21 etc... the number is properly adding for .index() but for .parent().index() it is appending the 1 as if it is a string!

Thought this was very curious, as I expected it to either act one way, or the other, not two different ways!

My first guess may be that it's because my `+ ", " +` is switching it to work as a string?

Comment: Instead of `$(this).index()` you can use `this.cellIndex` and instead of `$(this).parent().index()` you can use `this.parentNode.rowIndex`. Direct property access is much faster and more efficient that creating a jQuery object, then calling methods.

Comment: @RobG thanks, those worked, why am I able to use 'this' in place of '$(this)'? Also wondering because $(this).parentNode.rowIndex was a fail, but this.parentNode.rowIndex was a success.

Comment: The $ function creates a jQuery object. In a listener, *this* is usually set to the element calling the listener. So `$(this)` creates a jQuery object with one element. To reference the element, you need to do `$(this)[0]` which is just an inefficient way of accessing `this` (i.e. the element). `$(this).rowIndex` is attempting to access the *rowIndex* property of a jQuery object - it doesn't have one, it has an *index* method instead (that's what happens when you wrap DOM objects, simple property access becomes a function call).

Comment: @RobG thanks, do you know of a good reference that will show me all of the available properties and methods on the this (non-jQuery) object?

Comment: HTML DOM elements have properties that (more or less) mirror the equivalent [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/) attributes. You need to also read the [W3C DOM Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/) and [DOM HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/) specifications, and also the [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html) specification (noting that it is not a standard but does try to standarise common features that aren't in standards).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because JavaScript sees the first `index()` call returning a number to which it adds the number 1, then you're combining it with a string, so it concatenates the number to the string.

For addition, regardless of strings, use parentheses for isolation of the numbers from the strings:

```
$("#farmland td").click(function(){
        $("#console").html(($(this).index() + 1) + ", " + ($(this).parent().index() + 1));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to force a number evaluation of a var you can to something like 1*your_var and it will be interpreted as a number

Answer (score 0):

It's called left to right associativity.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation is kinda ugly when better tools are available. How about:

```
$("#farmland td").click(function(){
    $("#console").html([$(this).index() + 1, $(this).parent().index() + 1].join(", "));
});
```